# Can the Python walrus operator be used for type hinting generic functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Suppose I want to type hint a generic function in Python before 3.12, when the new parameter syntax was introduced:

```py
def max[T](args: Iterable[T]) -> T:
    ...
```

Then I have the option of using string type hints:

```py
def max(args: Iterable["T"]) -> "T":
    ...
```

Or typing variables:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def max(args: Iterable[T]) -> T:
    ...
```

I like the latter approach more, but introducing an extra global variable is definitely a drawback. I decided to combine generic type hinting with the walrus operator, like this:

```py
def max(args: Iterable[T := TypeVar("T")]) -> T:
    ...
```

Or

```py
def max(args: Iterable[T := int | float]) -> T:
    ...
```

Code like this runs without errors, but some typing libraries don't recognise this syntax. What are the drawbacks to writing code like this?

Comment: This question should be edited to make it focus on one problem only, and to avoid asking for recommendations.

Comment: `T` is still global; you just moved the definition and cluttered the function signature. Worse, it won't be obvious that you've redefined `T` when you try the same trick in a different function.

Comment: "Then I have the option of using string type hints:" This doesn't actually work like the other examples. It merely avoids a runtime error, but does not make `T` a type variable as in the other examples. Similarly, `T := int | float` does not define a type variable.

Comment: "Code like this runs without errors, but some typing libraries don't recognise this syntax." Have you actually found *any* type checker that accepts this? Both MyPy and PyLance reject the walrus-variants.

Comment: @chepner True, I didn't realise that `T` would still be global. But redefining `T` isn't a problem, because I never access its value, and it generates function signatures as expected. Cluttering the signature is a drawback, but on the other hand, putting typevar definition together with the function definition makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it did not get into documentation for some reason, but your question is addressed in [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics):

> A `TypeVar()` expression must always directly be assigned to a variable (it should not be used as part of a larger expression). The argument to `TypeVar()` must be a string equal to the variable name to which it is assigned. Type variables must not be redefined.

So, typecheckers should reject your suggested snippet. `mypy` [does](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=c8acfa25f6f7b658481da66edbb74946), `Pyright` [also does](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoCSMApiAIYBGANsQDRQAqixAamSALABQ33AJsWBQIZAB4AKdmgDOALkIly1YgG0GUWQF5GzNiHEAiBgYCUAXRNQAtAD5Gs7lCdQAdG%2B5A), and `Pyre` [does as well](https://pyre-check.org/play?input=from%20typing%20import%20Iterable%2C%20TypeVar%0A%0A%0Adef%20max(args%3A%20Iterable%5BT%20%3A%3D%20TypeVar(%22T%22)%5D)%20-%3E%20T%3A%0A%20%20%20%20...%0A).

So, the main drawback to writing code like this is the fact that such code is non-conformant and is not interpreted by typecheckers correctly.

Answer (score -2):

- As long as the type system is evolving (for the best!) the way it is
- When you don't control the environment your code is run/checked in (e.g. a distributed team)

I would opt for compatibility with established tools: this will save your coworkers a lot of surprises.  So: no walrus in the type hints :).